# Android: Unable to start AVD - Path problem?

Tags: android, sdk

My Android SDK is installed in c:\Program Files . When I try to start the AVD, I get this error. You can see that it appears to be a problem with the space in the name. How can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: Do you have emulator-arm.exe inside C://Files/Android/android-sdk-tools ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would move your android installation to a path that has no spaces in it. I put mine in C:\eclipse\android. Also be careful when adding libraries and jars that there are no spaces in the path to those names either.